# Incorrect Line Spacing in (term-mode, ansi-term, eshell, shell) Output

Tags: shell, eshell, ansi-term, line-spacing, term

The output of certain commands in multiple major modes (**term-mode**, **ansi-term**, **shell**, **eshell**) is incorrectly spaced (see images). This occurs for numerous commands and does not occur in other emulators (such as **xterm**) or a **tty**. It even happens when I've launched Emacs *without* loading an init file (using the -q flag). Does anyone know what might be causing this behavior?

**EDIT**: I've also tried adding colors to `less` (through [`bash`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Man_page#Colored_man_pages) and [`zsh`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1257467/3491710)) to no avail within **Emacs** but it works perfectly within **xterm**. I believe this is the same issue but hopefully it'll help someone help me.

[image: Odd spacing of Emacs output]

[image: Usual spacing for comparison]

Comment: Perhaps a terminfo issue? If you do not already [have the `eterm-color` support installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22091145/324105), do that and then try it again in `ansi-term` (`shell` and `eshell` are different).

Comment: Hey phils, it seems that `eterm-color` support is present on my machine because both **/usr/share/emacs/24.5/etc/e/{eterm-color,eterm-color.ti}** exist; the *ti file wasn't present in **/usr/share/terminfo/e/** but copying it there didn't help (nor did copying them both to **~/.terminfo** which didn't exist before).